# Is it possible to use Folder.jpg album artwork scheme?

Tags: music

I don't want to have to embed the album artwork into all of my music files. Oftentimes music players will look for the single file called Folder.jpg or Cover.jpg included in the folder with the music files. Does the music app support this, or does it plan to eventually?